# ASP.Net Application Cache for Web Services

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-services, caching

I have a web service with some data that I need to pass across sessions. I was thinking of using the application object.

> 1) Is this a good idea?
>
> 2) Some of the data will grow old and I'd like to purge 
>     it out so that the application object doesn't constantly 
>     grow. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your appdomain recycles, this data will be lost - will that be a problem?  If so, you should probably consider persisting this data somewhere else, probably a DB...

You could then cache this data and retrieve from the DB if the cache data is missing.

Comment: Lost data is not a problem. It's simply a cache that is regenerated when lost with little consequence.

Comment: Actually, I think that if he uses Cache or any application variable the data will not be lost between calls....

Comment: Quite, I didn't specify that, sorry, my thinking was that if he would have specific data to share between a few calls to a service, then he could run the risk of losing it.  If it can be easily regenerated, then just a simple cache makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the data size... but Cache sounds good to me.
If you realy need a good performance you could also implement distributed cache like memcached o NCache.